# What's the most efficient way to free the memory of pointers in a std::vector?

Tags: c++, performance, vector, c++17, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm writing a minesweeper clone and I have a `std::vector<Cell *> minefield`. I'm creating its content this way:

```
minefield.resize(cols * rows);
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        minefield[j + i * cols] = new Cell(j, i);
}
```

So, to avoid memory leaks I need to later `delete` the `Cell` objects in the main class (`Game`) destructor. What's the best (most efficient) way to do it?

Is it:

```
Game::~Game() {
    for (int i = 0; i < minefield.size(); ++i)
        delete minefield[i];
}
```

Or:

```
Game::~Game() {
    for (auto it = minefield.begin(); it != minefield.end(); ++it)
        delete *it;
}
```

Or maybe:

```
Game::~Game() {
    for (auto & m : minefield) // I'm not sure if the '&' should be here
        delete m;
}
```

?

Comment: Use of smart pointers, such as `std::unique_ptr`. Or avoid pointers altogether.

Comment: Try it at https://godbolt.org/ and see what you get. I would expect all of these to compile to the same or equivalent assembly with optimizations. All in all, you could just use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>` and have a safer and simpler solution.

Comment: I will be very surprised if there is any significant difference between them. For coding style, I prefer the last one.

Comment: What is the reason for using pointers here? Off the top of my head, I'd think `std::vector<Cell>` would be more appropriate.

Comment: The first step on the path of enlightenment is to forget about `new` and `delete` and pointers.

Comment: @Pete Becker I could use no pointers at all but then the `Cell` objects will get created on the stack, won't they? If not, how do I allocate the objects on the heap without pointers?

Comment: @atmostmediocre, they won't. When you add them to a `std::vector`, they will be created on the heap. However, you won't have to worry about managing their life time. `std::vector`'s implementation takes care of that for you.

Comment: @atmostmediocre -- they won't be on the stack, but even if they were, that won't be a problem. Presumably there's one `minefield` object, and for any reasonable number of mines (i.e., a number that you can display on the screen and that a human player can manage) it won't blow out the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need those dynamic allocations. You can delegate to std::vector the allocation and deallocation of the cell elements.

Try creating a minefield class that is a "matrix view" of a linear data allocated with a `std::vector`.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct cell
{
   std::size_t i, j;
   bool mine;
};

class minefield
{
public:
    minefield(int rows, int columns): cells(rows*columns), rowSize(columns)
    {
        std::cout << "just allocated std::vector\n";
    }
    virtual ~minefield()
    {
        std::cout << "about to free std::vector\n";
    }
    bool stepOn(std::size_t i, std::size_t j)
    {
        return cells.at(i*rowSize + j).mine;
    }
    void set(cell c)
    {
        cells[c.i*rowSize + c.j] = c;
    }
private:
    std::vector<cell> cells;
    int rowSize;
};


void funct() {
    minefield mf(5, 5);
    mf.set(cell{0, 0, false});
    mf.set(cell{0, 1, true});

    if (not mf.stepOn(0, 0))
    {
        std::cout << "still alive :)\n";
    }
    if (mf.stepOn(0, 1))
    {
        std::cout << "dead XP\n";
    }
}
int main()
{
    funct();
    std::cout << "bye!!\n";
}
```

This should print:

> just allocated std::vector
>
> still alive :)
>
> dead XP
>
> about to free std::vector
>
> bye!!